# Error while accessing iframe from chorme extension, content_security_policy error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy, chrome-plugins

I am trying to access the Iframe from the chrome plugin and get the below error.

> Refused to frame 'https://mysite.co/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *".

I have already added this below line in my menifest.json file but it not works.

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://mysite.co/"`

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I have to add `child-src` for the iframe as below.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://mysite.co; child-src https://mysite.co; object-src 'self'"
```